# Can't append options to <select> with jQuery andajax data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, append

im trying to add options to drop downs on the data provided by the web server. Im calling and all i get is [Object Object] added to the drop down in not HTML format.

```
$("div").on("click","#addproffbtn",function (event) {
        //$(this).parent().children() select selection
        var thing  = $(this);
        $.ajax({
        url : '/cmanager/getprofesor', 
        type : 'GET',
        success : function (data) {
           for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
              thing.parent().children()[1].append($('<option/>', {
                value: data[index].firstName,
                text: data[index].firstName
            }));
           }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
            "error thrown: " + errorThrown
        );
        }
    });
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
```

I've also tried a normal:

```
        append('<option value="'+data[index].firstName+'">'+data[index].firstName+'</option>')
```

Comment: can you show `data` variable doing `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Try replacing `thing.parent().children()[1]` with `thing.parent().find('select')`. You're selecting native dom node with `[0]` and applying native `append` 's method (not jQuery).

Comment: @mrlew `closest()` is for ancestors. `<select>` not likely an ancestor

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, I thought it was. Corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thing.parent().children()[1]` returns a dom element not a jQuery object

Try changing to

```
thing.parent().children().eq(1)// second child
// OR
thing.parent().find('select')
```

Showing your html structure would help if this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_data=[
     {
      value:'15',
      text:'text 15'
      },
     {
      value:'15',
      text:'text 16'
      }
];

for(var key in my_data){
 var _value=my_data[key].value;
 var _text=my_data[key].text;
 $('#my_select').append($('<option/>',{value : _value }).text(_text));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <select id="my_select">
   <option value="-1">Select item</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `[Object Object]` it means you're giving it the entire object rather than a property of that object. Also, it's not good practice to append a bunch of options individually. Instead, you can create a string of html that contains all of your options so that you only need to append it once.

```
$("div").on("click","#addproffbtn",function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  let options = '';

  $.ajax({
    url : '/cmanager/getprofesor', 
    type : 'GET',
    success : function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        options += `<option value="${item.firstName}">${item.firstName}<option/>`;
      });
      $('the selector for your select').append(options);      
    }
  });
});
```